# How to use or adapt this artificial plant?

Tags: hanging

I bought some hanging artificial plant that looks very much like this:

[image]

Notice the plant stem is oriented the same way as the plant itself, that means if I plant it in a pot it won't hang at all rather it will be upwards and look terrible. I don't know what they were thinking with such configuration, or am I missing something?

Is there a way to somehow use that stem so that the plant will hang? Because as it is now I have no clue what to make of that plant. It's a shame because it's particularly well designed otherwise (very realistic)

Comment: have you actually put it in a pot? ... the way you are describing it, you have not done it and you posted here before doing anything

Comment: Are you sure that's not designed to be a "vine" that gets attached to a wall? Drill a hole (if desired) stuff the "root" into it, then splay the tendrils any which way you want? Also, probably really belongs on [gardening.se] (I'm sure they've got an "artificial plant" tag, right?)

Comment: Set it free in the wild and see if it will adapt on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Not really home improvement but I'll try.  What if you took a plastic pot that you could hang, drill a hole in the bottom of it and insert the stem into the bottom of the pot. You could also put some artificial plant in the pot. Hey, I'm an engineer, what do you want..